# VBA: Find first row with exact date or later date

Tags: excel, vba

The code below shows me the first row in which the July 5th 2019 appears in column A. However, sometimes this exact date isn't in the column and I'd like to get the first row with a date after July 5th. How do I do that?

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find(CDate("05.07.19")).Row
End Sub
```

Comment: Btw. you might have some problems with date formats (at least pay attention to that) because it might be 17th May or 5th July depending on format

Answer (score 1):

I bet there are prettier ways, but this is one

```
Sub Test()
Dim Search As Range, myrng As Range
Dim rslt As Long, FRow As Long

Set myrng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")

Set Search = myrng.Find(CDate("05 July 19"))
If Not Search Is Nothing Then
    rslt = Search.Row 
Else
    Set Search = myrng.Find(Mid(CDate("July 2019"), 3, 6)
    If Not Search Is Nothing Then
        FRow = Search.Row
        Do Until Search Is Nothing
            If Day(Search) > 5 Then
                rslt = Search.Row
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set Search = myrng.FindNext(Search)
            If Not Search Is Nothing Then
                If Search.Row = FRow Then Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If
End If

Debug.Print rslt
```

As Prokurors rightfully points out though, the date format is likely to give problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this UDF:

```
Public Function GET_ROW_OF_DATE(ByVal vThisDate As Date, ByVal vOnThisRange As Range)

Dim rng As Range

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    If .CountIf(vOnThisRange, vThisDate) = 0 Then
        'if there is no exact match, count if any is higher
        If .CountIf(vOnThisRange, ">" & CDbl(vThisDate)) = 0 Then
            'There is no match
            GET_ROW_OF_DATE = 0
            Exit Function
        Else
            For Each rng In vOnThisRange
                If rng.Value > vThisDate Then
                    GET_ROW_OF_DATE = rng.Row
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Next rng
        End If
    Else
        'there is a match = to vThisDate
        For Each rng In vOnThisRange
            If rng.Value = vThisDate Then
                GET_ROW_OF_DATE = rng.Row
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next rng
    End If
End With

End Function
```

It there is no date equal or higher to the input, then it will return 0. Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Give this a try :

**Edited**

```
Sub tryme()

   Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A")

For Each c In rng.Cells
  If IsDate(c.Value) And c.Value = DateValue(Format("05/07/19", "dd/mm/yyyy")) Then
    firstValue = c.Value
    firstAddress = c.Address
    GoTo ENDSEARCH
  End If
Next

For Each c In rng.Cells
  If IsDate(c.Value) And c.Value > DateValue(Format("05/07/19", "dd/mm/yyyy")) Then
    firstValue = c.Value
    firstAddress = c.Address
    GoTo ENDSEARCH
  End If
Next


ENDSEARCH:
MsgBox "The first value greater than 05/07/2019 is in cell " & firstAddress & _
       "; - it has value " & firstValue


End Sub
```